# Count de dos tables SQL y que sume cuando sea diferente

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT 
t.SI_Articulo, 
m.SI_Descripcion,  
t.SI_UM,
(CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END) SI_OV, 
COUNT(DISTINCT t.SI_Ubicacion) SI_Ubicacion, 
SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia) SI_Existencia, 
(CASE WHEN SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad)END )SI_Cantidad,
(CASE WHEN SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia) IS NULL THEN 0 - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia) 
ELSE SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia) END ) SI_Dif,
(CASE WHEN SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia)* m.SI_Costo_Promedio IS NULL 
THEN 0 - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia) * m.SI_Costo_Promedio ELSE SUM(DISTINCT c.SI_Cantidad) - SUM(DISTINCT t.SI_Existencia)* m.SI_Costo_Promedio END) SI_Dif_Dinero 
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t 
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m ON m.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo 
LEFT JOIN SI_Conteo c ON c.SI_Num_Articulo = t.SI_Articulo AND c.SI_Num_Inventario = 1
LEFT JOIN SI_Consecutivo cs ON cs.SI_Num_Inventario = c.SI_Num_Inventario
GROUP BY t.SI_Articulo, 
         m.SI_Descripcion, 
         t.SI_UM, 
         (CASE WHEN c.SI_OV IS NOT NULL THEN '*' ELSE NULL END),
         m.SI_Costo_Promedio
```

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que en este Count `COUNT(DISTINCT t.SI_Ubicacion) SI_Ubicacion`  tengo estas 2 ubicaciones `cc3111, ee3091`  que esta en la tabla `SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t`  y necesito sumarle la ubicación que ingrese en la tabla `SI_Conteo c` la cual tiene 3 ubicaciones `cc3111, ee3091, ee2102` como se ve tiene 2 ubicaciones que son las mismas pero debe sumarle la que es diferente la cual es `ee2102` en total me debería mostrar que `SI_Ubicacion` tiene 3.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cómo se llama la columna en la tabla `SI_Conteo`?

Comment: `c.SI_Ubicacion` se llaman igual

Comment: la verdad, no se entiende bien la pregunta, pero suena a que quizás puedes reemplazar `COUNT(DISTINCT t.SI_Ubicacion)` por `COUNT(DISTINCT ISNULL(t.SI_Ubicacion,c.SI_Ubicacion))`

Comment: Que no entiende de la pregunta ?   seria contar la ubicación que están en la tabla `SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t`  y contar la ubicación que están en `SI_Conteo` y luego sumarla  pero por ejemplo si sumo las ubicaciones tal y como muestro en el ejemplo me da 5 y me debería dar 3 por que ya hay dos ubicaciones iguales, las ubicaciones iguales no las debería sumar.

Comment: al menos probaste el código que puse?

Comment: Si, pero me trae 2  las cuales deben de ser de `SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t`

Comment: Entonces no hay una tercera ubicación **para ese mismo articulo, con `SI_Num_Inventario= 1`** en la tabla `SI_Conteo`

Comment: La que tiene 2 es de la tabla `SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t` y la que tiene 3 es de la tabla `SI_conteo`

Comment: falta ver el valor de la columna `SI_Num_Inventario`

Comment: Ya la modifique.

Comment: la verdad es que viendo tus datos y la forma en que estás haciendo los joins, veo que los resultados que vas a obtener de las sumas y promedios no podrán ser correctos. Hay muchas ocasiones de multiplicidad de los datos. De todas formas, para el resultado particular que quieres en esta pregunta, tendrías que usar `COUNT(DISTINCT ISNULL(c.SI_Ubicacion,t.SI_Ubicacion))`

Comment: Si funciona de esa forma,  prestando atencion de tu comentario de los joins si tengo un error cuando por ejemplo en la imagen una el campo que le siguie despues de `SI_Articulo` es  `SI_Existencia`  el cual cada uno tiene una existencia de 1,  osea que la suma seria 2, pero cuando voy a ver el resultado me muestra 1 a no ser que sea por el `DISTINCT`

Comment: Alguna forma de arreglar los joins ?

Comment: Sorry, pero cada vez que voy viendo esto, se van agregando dificultades y detalles que no puedo saber de antemano sin conocer la estructura de tus tablas ni los datos que tienen, ni las reglas para cruzar las tablas ni el resultado que realmente se quiere obtener.